# MYSQL: Select column from table B if it exists, otherwise from table A

Tags: mysql, select

```
Table A
Name      Value
John      1
Mary      2
Gary      3

Table B
Name      Value
Jim       10
Jason     20
Mary      30
```

I want Name and Value from Table A, but overriding Value if exists in Table B. So my expected output would be:

```
John,1
Mary,30
Gary,3
```

I was trying something like:

```
SELECT A.Name, IF(EXISTS(B.Value),B.Value,A.Value) FROM Table A LEFT JOIN Table B on B.Name=A.Name
```

Comment: A problem such as this is generally indicative of a schema that violates the [Principle of Orthogonal Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_Orthogonal_Design).  Why isn't all such data in a single table, with a suitable differentiating column?

Comment: The example data was extremely simplied. Table A really has default values and can be used multiple times throughout a process. However, at different stages in the process, some values might need to be different. Since the process is dynamic and the different stages can fluctuate at any given time, it would be impossible to create the columns in a single row to account for future growth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Mysql `COALESCE` function for this. It will return the first non-null argument in a list of parameters:

So your code would look something like:

```
 SELECT A.Name, 
        coalesce(B.Value,A.Value) 
 FROM Table A LEFT JOIN Table B on B.Name=A.Name
```

So what would happens is that if there is a value in table B, that will be used, if not, it will revert to A.

See the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  A.Name,
  CASE WHEN b.Name IS NULL THEN a.Value ELSE b.value END AS value
FROM TableA  AS a
LEFT JOIN TableB AS b on B.Name=A.Name;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/907a68/2)